# At which point does map::emplace create an object?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Is the point at which `std::map::emplace` creates the object (i.e. call the constructor) specified somehow in standard? If yes, does it happen **before** existence of such key is checked or after?

It matters a lot in the cases like following:

```
struct X {};
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<X> > map;

void f(int x) {
    map.emplace(x, new X);
}
```

If object is created first, all is cool (unique_ptr is constructed and owns the resource), but if it is constructed after the check, there is a memory leak in case of a duplicate key.

All I was able to find in Standard is

> Inserts a value_type object t constructed with
>   `std::forward<Args>(args)...` if and only if there is no element in the
>   container with key equivalent to the key of t.

which doesn't address the question I have.

Comment: Using `new T` in an argument list is bad anyway, so the "real" answer is Don't Do That. Use `make_unique<X>()` and now it never leaks.

Comment: There will be a leak in any event if the allocation fails.

Comment: You usually don't emplace smart pointers because copying/moving them is fast and safe. Your question would make more sense if it was a `map<int, X>`

Comment: @GManNickG, this nortmatively calls constructor of unique_ptr twice (normal + move). Let's assume, I want to avoid it.

Comment: @T.C. if allocation fails, it would be a bad_alloc thrown. I do not care about memory leak at this point.

Comment: @SergeyA: There's nothing wrong with calling it twice. A move is literally copying a pointer and nulling another one; once inlining occurs and the compiler sees the destructor of the old one will do nothing, it costs nothing to copy this pointer around like you are doing anyway.

Comment: @GManNickG, it is all true, but we are diverting from the topic. Nowhere in standard it says anything about performance effiency of move contstructor for unique_ptr, and let's say, I'd like to be pico-seconds efficient. The question still stands.

Comment: @SergeyA: To answer your main question, it's simply under-specified; the standard fails to say if it needs to be one way or the other. The point of emplace, to me, is to avoid constructing the value_type if possible, so I would guess implementations attempt to avoid constructing it if possible. I haven't looked at any of them, though, and according to the standard text they could do it sometimes, all the time, or never (given the option).

Comment: @SergeyA: I think the question is fine in a language-lawyery kind of way, BTW. It's just unrealistic to need to care in your particular example.  If you care about performance that much, you would profile, find that most of your time is spent allocating and not copying a single pointer around (because unique_ptr calls were inlined), and look at ways to avoid saying `new T` in the first place. :)

Comment: @GManNickG, true. I admit, there is no practical reason for that. I am actually using `unique_ptr` in the code which triggered the question, but it made me curious. I fully accept 'under-specified' answer provided no other answers (which would explain it is specified in certain indirect way) appear a bit later.

Comment: @T.C. can you please clarify the comment that there will be a leak if allocation fails even if ```make_unique``` is used? I'm assuming you're referring to allocation for ```X```. If that fails and an exception is thrown, presumably that *can* be handled by ```emplace``` to deallocate the memory used to construct ```pair<int, unique_ptr<X>```, or am I missing something ? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is indeed underspecified, which is partially why C++17 added `try_emplace` to nail down the semantics. [N3873](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3873.html), an early version of the `try_emplace` proposal, has a good discussion on the existing wording.

In the general case, it has to be "before", as "after" is unimplementable, and the standard would be defective if it imposed such a requirement. Consider `emplace(piecewise_construct, forward_as_tuple(foo, bar), forward_as_tuple(meow, purr))`. As the key and value are not required to be movable, you pretty much have to construct the object first and check the key's existence second, because you can't check for the key's existence without the key.

It is not inconceivable, however, that an implementation might want to special-case `emplace(key_type, something)`; it's usually a Good Thing to avoid paying for the required allocation + construction + destruction + deallocation when the key exists.